# Integration that results to give bessels function

Tags: integration

I have to integrate the following :

$$\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{(-ax^p-bx^{-q})}dx$$

Please help me I am not able to solve this .. However there is this identity available in a book

$$\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{(-ax^p-bx^{-p})}dx = 2 p^{-1}(\frac{b}{a})^{(\frac{p}{2s})}K_{(\frac{s}{p})}(2a^{(\frac{1}{2})}b^{(\frac{1}{2})})$$

where K is first kind bessels function.
I am not able to reprove the identity in the book, even if we can do that, it will eventually lead to the solution of the question.

Comment: Can you give a reference to the book? And indeed math.stackexchange is a better place.

Comment: Note that the integral is of the form of gamma function. U can use the relation between gamma function and first kind bessel function.